# Social Login without outh or auth laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need reference or way to do social login without outh in laravel.I have made custom controller for login and register as UserController.php in which I have written below method:

```
public function user_login(Request $request)
  {
    $email=$request->input('email');
    $password=$request->input('password');
    $user=DB::table('user')->where('email',$email)->where('password',$password) ->get();
    if(count($user)==1)
    {
      Session::put('id_user',$user[0]->id);
      return '1';
    }else {
      return '0';
    }
  }
```

Registration:

```
public function add(Request $request)
  {
    $f_name=$request->input('f_name');
    $l_name=$request->input('l_name');
    $email=$request->input('email');
    $password=$request->input('password');
    $contactno=$request->input('contactno');
    $return=$id_user="";
    $chk=DB::table('user')->where('contactno',$contactno)->orWhere('email',$email)->get();
    if(count($chk)==0)
    {
      $id_user=DB::table('user')->insertGetId(['f_name'=>$f_name,'l_name'=>$l_name,'email'=>$email, 'contactno'=>$contactno,'password'=>$password,]);

      if($id_user > 0)
      {
        Session::put('id_user',$id_user);
        $return='1';
      }else {
        $return='0';
      }
    }else {
      $return='2';
    }

    $data=array('return'=>$return,'id_user'=>$id_user);
    return json_encode($data);
  }
```

As I read my blogs in that they use auth. As I am not using auth in my project.But now I dont know how to do social login.
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: Don't store plain text passwords in your database!

Comment: Why not use default Laravel Auth? Did you take a look at [Laravel Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/socialite)?

Comment: I am new in laravel n auth making me very confuse